# Swift AppIntent Parameters. How to trap errors?

Tags: swift, swiftui, siri, sirishortcuts, appintents

I have a very simple AppIntent but Siri is easily confused when capturing parameters and responds with "Something went wrong" then silently terminates the process - how do I see the error and ask the user to try again?

The error happens before the Perform method and only when running on a handset.

```
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI

enum MyValues: String {
    
    case no
    case alittle
    case alot
    
}

extension MyValues: AppEnum {
    
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Choose values"
    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [MyValues: DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .no: "No",
        .alittle: "A little",
        .alot: "A lot"
    ]
    
    static var scoreFromValue: [MyValues: Int] = [
        .no: 1,
        .alittle: 3,
        .alot: 5
    ]
    
}


struct MyIntent: AppIntent {
    
    static private func score(values: [Int]) -> String {
        let result = values.reduce(1, *)
        return String(result)
    }
    
    
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Values Questionnaire"
    
    @Parameter(title: "value1", requestValueDialog:("Question 1?") )
    var valueOne: MyValues
    
    @Parameter(title: "value2", requestValueDialog:("Question 2?"))
    var valueTwo: MyValues
    
    @Parameter(title: "value3", requestValueDialog:("Question 3?"))
    var valueThree: MyValues
    
    @Parameter(title: "value4", requestValueDialog: ("Question 4?"))
    var valueFour: MyValues
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult{
        
        return .result(dialog: """
            I got \(valueOne.rawValue), \(valueTwo.rawValue), \(valueThree.rawValue) and  \(valueFour.rawValue) which is a score of \(MyIntent.score(values: [MyValues.scoreFromValue[valueOne] ?? 0, MyValues.scoreFromValue[valueTwo] ?? 0, MyValues.scoreFromValue[valueThree] ?? 0, MyValues.scoreFromValue[valueFour] ?? 0]))
            """)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `perform()` function isn’t doing any actual stuff besides returning the result. Maybe that’s the issue here or was this just an oversight in your example?

Comment: yes that's right the Perform error is just for demo purposes, the problem happens when Siri gets the parameter values, which is something out of the developer's control. What do we do if it fails?